# How to click an option value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to click a certain option inside the div  tag using Javascript .

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="sizes" data-info="product_sizes" id="select_size">
    <div id="sizes" style="display: block;">
        <select size="8" id="product_sizes">
            <option value="06.5" data-modelsize="06_5" data-sfs="false" class="">06.5</option>
            <option value="07.0" data-modelsize="07_0" data-sfs="false" class="">07.0</option>
```

I want to click the option value how would I go by doing this using Javascript.

Comment: Are you attempting to have one of the options be selected?

If so: `$(/*Whatever element you want*/).prop('selected', true);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just target the `select` and set the value:

```
$("#product_sizes").val("06.5");
```

If you want to trigger the `change` event, add `.change()` to the above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to click it, just set the selectedIndex ir value of the `<select>`.

Without jQuery, this is how to do it:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('product_sizes');
sel.selectedIndex = 1; // selects 07.0
// Setting the value works too:
// sel.value = "07.0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
/**
* OPT ID
*/
var opt = 3;
/**
* SELECTED
*/
var elements = $('#product_sizes option');
$(elements[ opt ]).attr("selected","selected").prop("selected",true);

/**
* OR SET VALUE
*/
$('#product_sizes').val( 19.5 );

/**
* CATCH
*/
$("#product_sizes").change(function(){
    console.log( $( this ).val() );
});
```